# SQL to return results for the following regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following regular expression:

```
WHERE A.srvc_call_id = '40750564' AND REGEXP_LIKE (A.SRVC_CALL_DN, '[^TEST]')
```

The row that contains 40750564 has "TEST CALL" in the column `SRVC_CALL_DN` and `REGEXP_LIKE` doesn't seem to be filtering it out. Whenever I run the query it returns the row when it shouldn't.

Is my regex pattern wrong? Or does SQL not accept `[^whatever]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carat anchors the expression to the start of a string. By enclosing the letters T, E, S & T in square brackets you're searching, as [barsju suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017125/458741) for *any* of these characters, not for the string TEST.

You say that `SRVC_CALL_DN` *contains* the string `'TEST CALL'`, but you don't say where in the string. You also say that you're looking for where this string *doesn't* match. This implies that you want to use `not regexp_like(...`

Putting all this together I think you need:

```
AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (A.SRVC_CALL_DN, '^TEST[[:space:]]CALL')
```

This *excludes* every match from your query where the string *starts with* `'TEST CALL'`. However, if this string may be in any position in the column you need to remove the carat - `^`.

This also assumes that the string is always in upper case. If it's in mixed case or lower, then you need to change it again. Something like the following:

```
AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (upper(A.SRVC_CALL_DN), '^TEST[[:space:]]CALL')
```

By upper-casing `SRV_CALL_DN` you ensure that you're always going to match but ensure that your query may not use an index on this column. I wouldn't worry about this particular point as regular expressions queries can be fairly poor at using indexes anyway and it appears as though `SRVC_CALL_ID` is indexed.

Also if it *may* not include `'CALL'` you will have to remove this. It is best when using regular expressions to make your match pattern as explicit as possible; so include `'CALL'` if you can.

Comment: My intention was to exclude any rows with "test" in SRVC_CALL_DN. I used your suggestion with NON REGEXP_LIKE, which worked ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try with `'^TEST'` or `'^TEST.*'`

Your regexp means any string not starting with any of the characters: T,E,S,T.

But your case is so simple, starts with TEST. Why not use a simple like:

```
LIKE 'TEST%'
```